# add +1 hour to datetime.time() django on forloop

Tags: python, django

I have code like this, I want to check in the time range that has overtime and sum it.

currently, am trying `out.hour+1` with this code, but didn't work.

```
    overtime_all = 5
    overtime_total_hours = 0
    out = datetime.time(14, 30)

    while overtime_all > 0:
        overtime200 = object.filter(time__range=(out, out.hour+1)).count()
        overtime_total_hours = overtime_total_hours + overtime200
        overtime_all -=1

    print overtime_total_hours
```

how to add `1` hour every loop?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timedelta (from `datetime`) can be used to increment or decrement a `datatime` objects. Unfortunately, it cannot be directly combined with `datetime.time` objects.

If the values that are stored in your `time` column are `datetime` objects, you can use them (e.g.: `my_datetime + timedelta(hours=1)`). If they are `time` objects, you'll need to think if they represent a moment in time (in that case, they should be converted to `datetime` objects) or a duration (in that case, it's probably easier to store it as an integer representing the total amount of minutes, and to perform all operations on integers).

Comment: Except `overtime_all` is an integer here so that's not going to work...

Comment: Indeed, I changed it. But the idea is there.

Comment: Sure... I think the key thing the OP is missing is being able to make that `hours=1` be `hours=2` - so they need a variable somewhere for that... (byt yes... using a timedelta here to handle crossing days etc... is a good idea)

Comment: I agree. Moreover, time object and timedelta cannot be added togheter (I think one has to first convert a time object to a datetime, e.g. based on current date). I'll update my answer asap

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution now, and this is work.

```
    overtime_all = 5
    overtime_total_hours = 0
    out = datetime.time(14, 30)

    while overtime_all > 0:
        overtime200 = object.filter(time__range=(out,datetime.time(out.hour+1, 30))).count()
        overtime_total_hours = overtime_total_hours + overtime200
        overtime_all -=1

    print overtime_total_hours
```

i do change `out.hour+1` to `datetime.time(out.hour+1, 30)` its work fine now, but i dont know maybe there more compact/best solution.

thank you guys for your answer.

Comment: Time objects only accept hours<24. If you want to represent duration, I again advise you to store it using an integer, not a time object...

Comment: yea, facing that problem, will try using an integer.